# Replacing a character with a new line in a string in a list in python

Tags: python

I have one long string of numbers in a list. The numbers are separated with the character '\r'.

Looks something like this:

`['5214661\r3392815\r4498905\r309361\r5214080\r3020583\r3089870\r802553\r4254266\r1395033']`

I'm trying to simply replace the character with a line break so that each number gets its own line, as such:

```
'5214661'
'3392815'
'4498905'
'309361'
'5214080'
... etc.
```

Comment: `lst[0] = lst[0].replace('\r', '\n')`?

Comment: just do splitting on \r

Comment: i've tried print([s.replace('\r', '\n') for s in Data])  and it only displays the first "number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_string_list = ['5214661\r3392815\r4498905\r309361\r5214080\r3020583\r3089870\r802553\r4254266\r1395033']

for my_number in my_string_list[0].split('\r'):
    print my_number

#Output
5214661
3392815
...
1395033
```

Is this what you need?

You can also do this in single line as:

```
print my_string_list[0].replace("\r", "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `splitlines()`

```
print("\n".join(k[0].splitlines()))
```

In the REPL

```
>>> k = ['5214661\r3392815\r4498905\r309361\r5214080\r3020583\r3089870\r802553\r4254266\r1395033']
>>> print("\n".join(k[0].splitlines()))
5214661
3392815
4498905
309361
5214080
3020583
3089870
802553
4254266
1395033
```